# Adaptive Rejection Sampling in python?

Tags: sampling, python, pymc, rejection-sampling

[Adaptive Rejection Sampling](https://stat.duke.edu/~cnk/Links/slides.pdf) is a sampling technique for uni-dimensional variables that takes profit of the log-concavity of the probability density. It is used, for instance, in Gibbs sampling, when some variable has not a conjugate prior but its density is log-concave.

I have a python implementation of a Gibbs sampler where, indeed, one of the variables with non-conjugate priors can be sampled by ARS. Since there is an [R implementation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ars/ars.pdf), I call this R function from python.

Yet, calls to R from python are too costly to do it at every iteration, and therefore I would like to implement the ARS directly in python. So, since I don't want to reinvent the wheel:

*Is there already any python implementation of Adaptive Rejection Sampling?* 
(either a library or an implementation shared by some practitioner)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I uploaded an ARS implementation to GitHub. Thanks to [John Greenall](http://sourceforge.net/p/scikit-learn/mailman/scikit-learn-general/thread/B963733A3B7F9845815FF33B96FFDCBA016E8266F04F@HERMES8.ds.leeds.ac.uk/) who kindly shared his original implementation with me:

https://github.com/alumbreras/ARS

```
import numpy as np
import random

class ARS():
    '''
    This class implements the Adaptive Rejection Sampling technique of Gilks and Wild '92.
    Where possible, naming convention has been borrowed from this paper.
    The PDF must be log-concave.
    Currently does not exploit lower hull described in paper- which is fine for drawing
    only small amount of samples at a time.
    '''

    def __init__(self, f, fprima, xi=[-4,1,4], lb=-np.Inf, ub=np.Inf, use_lower=False, ns=50, **fargs):
        '''
        initialize the upper (and if needed lower) hulls with the specified params

        Parameters
        ==========
        f: function that computes log(f(u,...)), for given u, where f(u) is proportional to the
           density we want to sample from
        fprima:  d/du log(f(u,...))
        xi: ordered vector of starting points in wich log(f(u,...) is defined
            to initialize the hulls
        use_lower: True means the lower sqeezing will be used; which is more efficient
                   for drawing large numbers of samples


        lb: lower bound of the domain
        ub: upper bound of the domain
        ns: maximum number of points defining the hulls
        fargs: arguments for f and fprima
        '''

        self.lb = lb
        self.ub = ub
        self.f = f
        self.fprima = fprima
        self.fargs = fargs

        #set limit on how many points to maintain on hull
        self.ns = 50
        self.x = np.array(xi) # initialize x, the vector of absicassae at which the function h has been evaluated
        self.h = self.f(self.x, **self.fargs)
        self.hprime = self.fprima(self.x, **self.fargs)

        #Avoid under/overflow errors. the envelope and pdf are only
        # proporitional to the true pdf, so can choose any constant of proportionality.
        self.offset = np.amax(self.h)
        self.h = self.h-self.offset 

        # Derivative at first point in xi must be > 0
        # Derivative at last point in xi must be < 0
        if not(self.hprime[0] > 0): raise IOError('initial anchor points must span mode of PDF')
        if not(self.hprime[-1] < 0): raise IOError('initial anchor points must span mode of PDF')
        self.insert() 


    def draw(self, N):
        '''
        Draw N samples and update upper and lower hulls accordingly
        '''
        samples = np.zeros(N)
        n=0
        while n < N:
            [xt,i] = self.sampleUpper()
            ht = self.f(xt, **self.fargs)
            hprimet = self.fprima(xt, **self.fargs)
            ht = ht - self.offset
            ut = self.h[i] + (xt-self.x[i])*self.hprime[i]

            # Accept sample? - Currently don't use lower
            u = random.random()
            if u < np.exp(ht-ut):
                samples[n] = xt
                n +=1

            # Update hull with new function evaluations
            if self.u.__len__() < self.ns:
                self.insert([xt],[ht],[hprimet])

        return samples


    def insert(self,xnew=[],hnew=[],hprimenew=[]):
        '''
        Update hulls with new point(s) if none given, just recalculate hull from existing x,h,hprime
        '''
        if xnew.__len__() > 0:
            x = np.hstack([self.x,xnew])
            idx = np.argsort(x)
            self.x = x[idx]
            self.h = np.hstack([self.h, hnew])[idx]
            self.hprime = np.hstack([self.hprime, hprimenew])[idx]

        self.z = np.zeros(self.x.__len__()+1)
        self.z[1:-1] = (np.diff(self.h) - np.diff(self.x*self.hprime))/-np.diff(self.hprime) 

        self.z[0] = self.lb; self.z[-1] = self.ub
        N = self.h.__len__()
        self.u = self.hprime[[0]+range(N)]*(self.z-self.x[[0]+range(N)]) + self.h[[0]+range(N)]

        self.s = np.hstack([0,np.cumsum(np.diff(np.exp(self.u))/self.hprime)])
        self.cu = self.s[-1]


    def sampleUpper(self):
        '''
        Return a single value randomly sampled from the upper hull and index of segment
        '''
        u = random.random()

        # Find the largest z such that sc(z) < u
        i = np.nonzero(self.s/self.cu < u)[0][-1] 

        # Figure out x from inverse cdf in relevant sector
        xt = self.x[i] + (-self.h[i] + np.log(self.hprime[i]*(self.cu*u - self.s[i]) + 
        np.exp(self.u[i]))) / self.hprime[i]

        return [xt,i]
```

And here are the three examples used in the [ARS R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ars/)

```
from __future__ import  division
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from  ars import ARS


######################################
# Example 1: sample 10000 values 
# from the normal distribution N(2,3)
######################################
def f(x, mu=0, sigma=1):
    """ 
    Log Normal distribution 
    """
    return -1/(2*sigma**2)*(x-mu)**2

def fprima(x, mu=0, sigma=1):
    """
    Derivative of Log Normal distribution
    """
    return -1/sigma**2*(x-mu)

x = np.linspace(-100,100,100)
ars = ARS(f, fprima, xi = [-4,1,40], mu=2, sigma=3)
samples = ars.draw(10000)
plt.hist(samples, bins=100, normed=True)
plt.show()


######################################
# Example 2: sample 10000 values 
# from a gamma(2,0.5)
######################################
def f(x, shape, scale=1):
    """ 
    Log gamma distribution 
    """
    return (shape-1)*np.log(x)-x/scale


def fprima(x, shape, scale=1):
    """
    Derivative of Log gamma distribution
    """
    return (shape-1)/x-1/scale

x = np.linspace(-100,100,100)
ars = ARS(f, fprima, xi = [0.1,1,40], lb=0, shape=2, scale=0.5)
samples = ars.draw(10000)
plt.hist(samples, bins=100, normed=True)
plt.show()


######################################
# Example 3: sample 10000 values 
# from a beta(1.3,2.7) distribution
######################################
def f(x, a=1.3, b=2.7):
    """ 
    Log beta distribution 
    """
    return (a-1)*np.log(x)+(b-1)*np.log(1-x)


def fprima(x, a=1.3, b=2.7):
    """
    Derivative of Log beta distribution
    """
    return (a-1)/x-(b-1)/(1-x)

x = np.linspace(-100,100,100)
ars = ARS(f, fprima, xi = [0.1, 0.6], lb=0, ub=1, a=1.3, b=2.7)
samples = ars.draw(10000)
plt.hist(samples, bins=100, normed=True)
plt.show()
```